# Update The Date Field on Change in month/Year -Jquery Date Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to customize Jquery datepicker. I have a requirement **to Update the Date on input field when Year or Month is Changed without clicking date. That is, Datepicker must update the field even if the date(days) is not clicked if there is already a date in field**. Is it possible to update *"target date field"* like that?

I've done a lot of searching but couldn't find a feasible solution.

```
<input type="text" id="DatePickerTest">



$(document).ready(function() {

$("#DatePickerTest").datepicker({

changeMonth:true,
changeYear:true,
showButtonPanel:true

});
```

Please Share your knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

**Inside document ready**

```
//To Add DatePicker
        $("#DatePickerTest").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
            onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
                var date = $("#DatePickerTest").val();
                if ($.trim(date) != "") {
                    var newDate = month + "/" + inst.currentDay + "/" + year;
                    $("#DatePickerTest").val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/M/yy', new Date(newDate)));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks Alot .. 'onChangeMonthYear' is working perfectly for me..